# Can a PDF be viewed inline in a WPF control using Edge?

Tags: .net, wpf, internet-explorer, windows-10

To the best of my current understanding, "native" PDF viewing in Windows 10 is accomplished via the Edge browser. Has anyone successfully used this to implement an embedded PDF viewer in a WPF application, and, if so, using what set of controls / classes?

I'm looking to move away from invoking Acrobat Reader via COM/ActiveX as we migrate our users to Windows 10.

Comment: http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/  But I don't know about Windows 10.  Only a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this.

If I'm not mistaken, PDF related functionality is exposed via [Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument) and related API's. These do not have [TargetDeviceFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx)=Desktop, and thus are unlikely to be usable by a WPF application.